# TableCollection.add throws 'InvalidArgument' error when the sheet name has special characters

Tags: office365, office-js, excel-addins

We have built a Excel Task Pane add-in that primarily works with Tables. We have some code that executes TableCollection.add(rangeAddress, true). This call fails when the sheet name in the 'rangeAddress' contain special characters.

For example -

```
ctx.workbook.tables.add(Sheet!A1:E4, true)
```

works fine but,

```
ctx.workbook.tables.add(Sheet-Name!A1:E4, true)
```

throws error

```
{
"name": "OfficeExtension.Error",
"code": "InvalidArgument",
"message": "The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.",
"traceMessages": [],
"debugInfo": {
    "errorLocation": "TableCollection.add"
}
```

}

Please note that the second example address has special character '-' in its sheet name. Is there a way to support special characters in sheet name?

Comment: I'm assuming the sheet name & address are quoted...  But that aside, what platform (desktop, online, Mac, iOS) are you using -- and what version number?

Comment: Yes, rangeAddress (sheet-name&address) is quoted (string). It happens across all the platforms (not sure about iOS)

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky are you not able to reproduce this? do you need any other info?

Comment: What platform (desktop, online, Mac, iOS) are you using -- and what version number?

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky As I mentioned above it is reproducible across all the platforms. To provide you specific details, can you check for Mac desktop (version - 15.29 (161101))

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed this comment earlier in the week.  Let me investigate and get back to you early next week.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with the APIs... per se. Nor is it with tables.

In Excel, if you create a cross-sheet reference, and if the sheet name has non alpha-numeric characters (or something of that sort), you will see that the formula gets written as `='Some-Hyphenated-Sheet'!C27`  Note that the sheet name is surrounded with **single quotes**.

The API is just a reflection of native Excel functionality, so you would need to single-quote the sheet name as well.  That is:

```
ctx.workbook.tables.add("'Sheet-Name'!A1:E4", true)
```