# Unable to create table in excel web add-in

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I have written a function to create table

After investigating on issue : -
the issue is code works fine on adding table with name "tableName" on one sheet but if I insert another table on some other sheet with same name "tableName" it throws an error and does not insert table but without contents.
I need to apply name to table as I want to retrive table as per need and I am doing it with the help of its name.Read an article [on table naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40127960/tablecollection-add-throws-invalidargument-error-when-the-sheet-name-has-speci) but what if I rename sheet name then how to access it .

---

**Error**:
    Something went wrong!!!  RichApi.Error: The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.
    at new c (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/excel-web-16.00.js:24:293355)
    at b.f.processRequestExecutorResponseMessage (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/excel-web-16.00.js:24:354008)
    at https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/excel-web-16.00.js:24:352113
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (https://localhost/excelProject/polyfills.js:2753:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (https://localhost/excelProject/vendor.js:57267:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (https://localhost/excelProject/polyfills.js:2752:52)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (https://localhost/excelProject/polyfills.js:2512:43)
    at https://localhost/excelProject/polyfills.js:3251:34
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (https://localhost/excelProject/polyfills.js:2785:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (https://localhost/excelProject/vendor.js:57258:33)

---

**Code** :

```
createTable(tableName, startColumn, endColumn, headerData, bodyData, onTableChangedCallback, onSelectionChangedCallback){
Excel.run((context)=> {
  var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
  let colRange = startColumn+":"+endColumn;//like B2:D2
  var sfTable = sheet.tables.add(colRange, true /*hasHeaders*/);
  sfTable.name = "tableName";
  let headerRow = [];
  headerRow.push(headerData);//Below code is hardcoded for 4 column for now


  var tableHeaderRange = sfTable.getHeaderRowRange();
  tableHeaderRange.values = 
  [["Date", "Merchant", "Category", "Amount"]];

  sfTable.rows.add(null /*add rows to the end of the table*/, 
    [
      ["1/1/2017", "The Phone Company", "Communications", "$120"],
      ["1/2/2017", "Northwind Electric Cars", "Transportation", "$142"],
      ["1/5/2017", "Best For You Organics Company", "Groceries", "$27"],
      ["1/10/2017", "Coho Vineyard", "Restaurant", "$33"],
      ["1/11/2017", "Bellows College", "Education", "$350"],
      ["1/15/2017", "Trey Research", "Other", "$135"],
      ["1/15/2017", "Best For You Organics Company", "Groceries", "$97"]
  ]);



  if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("ExcelApi", "1.2")) {
      sheet.getUsedRange().format.autofitColumns();
      //sheet.getUsedRange().format.autofitRows();
      sheet.getUsedRange().format.rowHeight = 15;
  }
  sfTable.onChanged.add(onTableChangedCallback);
  sfTable.onSelectionChanged.add(onSelectionChangedCallback)
  sheet.activate();

  return context.sync(); 
})
.catch((err)=>{
  this.errorHandlerFunction(err,"create table")
});
```

}

Comment: I am not be able to repro this issue, I have tried to use your function in my code,  could you please review and update if necessary to repro this issue? thanks 
Here is my gist:
https://gist.github.com/lumine2008/b3d9261f0c6dc9f6a31078fa1b72a8dc

Comment: were you able to create table on each sheet of excel web??

Comment: Yes, I can create tables sucessfully with my gist, can you please have a try with this gist: gist.github.com/lumine2008/b3d9261f0c6dc9f6a31078fa1b72a8dc

Comment: @RaymondLu please read question I have changed few points ..And thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Do you want to create 2 tables with the same name?

Comment: yes but one on each sheet .The issue is ,for now, solved using a workaround ,but I am interested in knowing correct method .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of error was very unusual .But issue was with tables having same name .Error was removed when i named them differently .